# Bootstrap 3 tab in Knockoutjs foreach

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a bootstrap `nav-tab` populated by knockoutjs `foreach`.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: threshold_list">
    <li data-bind="css: $index() == 0 ? 'active' : ''"><a class="text-capitalize" data-toggle="tab" 
        data-bind="attr: { href: '#ftabs-' + $index() }, text: name()"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the `tab-content`:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'tab-content-' + name() }" class="tab-content">
    <!-- ko foreach: threshold_list -->
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: 'ftabs-' + $index() }, css: $index() == 0 ? 'tab-pane fade in active' : 'tab-pane fade'">

        </div>
    <!-- ko -->
</div>
```

Both pieces of code are inside an other `foreach` loop.

The navigation active class changes depending on the link I have typed, but the tab doesn’t change.

How can I fix this?

Comment: These bindings set the first item in `threshold_list` active, they don't depend on what link you have typed. Base the CSS binding on an observable, not on `$index`.

Comment: Can you write an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this as there are some syntax errors(fixed)

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.threshold_list=ko.observable([1,2,3,4]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**View:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: threshold_list">
    <li data-bind="css: $index() == 0 ? 'active' : ''"><a class="text-capitalize" data-toggle="tab" 
        data-bind="attr: { href: '#ftabs-' + $index() }, text: $data"></a></li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="foreach: threshold_list" class="tab-content" >
        <div data-bind="attr:{ id:'ftabs-'+$index() }, css: $index() == 0 ? 'tab-pane fade in active':'tab-pane fade',text:$data">
        </div>
</div>
```

Working sample Fiddler **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2VmmW/350/)**

*Bootstrap Tabs inside Model-pop version*

Working fiddler **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2VmmW/352/)**

Comment: This sample in Fiddle works, thank you, but not in my context. I have the same bad behaviour. When close the modal where this tabs live and open it again, I can toggle only last tabs, so in your sample only tab3 or tab4 and even if I click on tab1 or tab2, tab content doesn't switch.

Comment: its doesn't seem to be the case with me , check the added fiddle . reproduce your issue using above fiddlers and let us know(if you still face a issue) .

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it works.

I'm not handling properly `observableArray` for load dynamically modals.

Now when a modal hides, I remove it from array.

Thank you all